# R doubling list length when subsetting

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I am currently trying to subset a list in R from a dataframe. My current attempt looks like:

```
list.level <- unique(buckets$group)
bucket.group <- vector("list",length(list.level))

for(i in list.level){
  bucket.group[[i]] <- subset(buckets$group,buckets$group == i)
}
```

However, instead of filling the list it seems to create a duplicate list of the same amount of rows, returning:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

...

NULL

[[22]]
NULL

[[23]]
NULL

$A
[1] "A"

$C
[1] "C" "C" "C"

$D
[1] "D" "D" "D"

...

$AJ
[1] "AJ" "AJ" "AJ" "AJ" "AJ"

$AK
[1] "AK" "AK"
```

A should be filling into 1, C into 2, etc. etc. How do I get these to fill in the original rows rather than creating extra rows at the bottom of the list?

Comment: Can you make your example [reproducible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
list.level <- unique(buckets$group)
bucket.group <- vector("list",length(list.level))

for(i in 1:length(list.level)){
  bucket.group[[i]] <- subset(buckets$group,buckets$group == list.level[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is going on. Suppose your `buckets$group` is `c("a","a","b","b")`.

```
list.level <- unique(buckets$group)
```

Now `list.level` is `c("a","b")`

```
bucket.group <- vector("list",length(list.level))
```

Since `length(list.level)` is 2, now your `bucket.group` is a list of 2 NULL elements, their names are 1 and 2.

```
for(i in list.level){
```

Recalling the value of `list.level`, it is the same as `for i in c("a","b")`.

```
     bucket.group[[i]] <- subset(buckets$group,buckets$group == i)
```

Since `i` loops over `"a"` and `"b"`, you now fill `bucket.group[["a"]]` and `bucket.group[["b"]]`, while `bucket.group[[1]]` and `bucket.group[[2]]` remain intact.

To fix this, you should write instead

```
list.level <- unique(buckets$group) # ok, this was correct
bucket.group <- list() # just empty list   
for(i in 1:length(list.level)){
  bucket.group[[i]] <- buckets$group[buckets$group == list.level[[i]] ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your `for` statement.

Your code is like this:

```
list.level<-letters[1:10]
> for(i in list.level) print(i)
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "c"
[1] "d"
[1] "e"
[1] "f"
[1] "g"
[1] "h"
[1] "i"
[1] "j"
```

It assigns each element in `list.level` to i, so `i` is a letter. When you do
    `bucket.group[[i]] <- subset(buckets$group,buckets$group == i`)
in the first iteration, `i` is a letter. So it looks for a list element called `bucket.group[["a"]]` and does not find it, so it creates it and stores the data there. If instead you use `seq_along`

```
for(i in seq_along(list.level)) print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

now `i` will alway be a number and the code will do what you want.

So use `seq_along` instead.